# enable iterative calculation mode in excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, iteration

How do I enable iterative calculation option in Excel through C#?

I know how do it through the UI inside excel, but I would like to allow my program to change it via the Excel Interop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.Iteration` is the property to set to `true`.