# How to force recalculation (F9 feature) through C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How to force recalculation (F9 feature) through C#? Is there a particular position to place the code in, *such as towards the end*, after data is populated?

Comment: Looking at your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172760/enable-iterative-calculation-mode-in-excel-using-c), I would suggest you fire up Excel, go to the code editor, press F2 and look through the list at your leisure.

Comment: wow, that would be really useful, tx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick one that suits you best.

```
Application.Calculate
Application.CalculateFull
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

Comment: Some brief descriptions available on the ms docs site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Application.CalculateFull
```